# How to melt a dataframe in Pandas with the option for removing NA values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"VAR1":["V1","V2","V2","V3","V4","V4","V5"], "VAR2":["C1","C1","C1","C2","C2","C2","C3"], "VAR3":["S1","S2","S3","S4","","",""], "VAR4":["","S3","S4","S5","S6","",""], "VAR5":["","S7","","","","","S3"]})

df
```

I have to transform this into a dataframe that looks like this

```
VAR1  VAR2  VALUE
V1     C1    S1
V2     C1    S2
V2     C1    S3
V2     C1    S7
V3     C2    S4
V3     C2    S5
V4     C2    S6
V5     C3    S3
```

That is, I want to melt the `VAR, VAR4, VAR5` columns into a single column based on their mapping with `VAR1 and VAR2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for remove rows where empty values, then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) in columns and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for default monotonic unique `index`:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['VAR1', 'VAR2'], value_name='VALUE').drop('variable', axis=1)
df = df[df.VALUE != ''].sort_values(['VAR1','VAR2']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  VAR1 VAR2 VALUE
0   V1   C1    S1
1   V2   C1    S2
2   V2   C1    S3
3   V2   C1    S3
4   V2   C1    S4
5   V2   C1    S7
6   V3   C2    S4
7   V3   C2    S5
8   V4   C2    S6
9   V5   C3    S3
```

Also if need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['VAR1', 'VAR2'], value_name='VALUE').drop('variable', axis=1)
df = df[df.VALUE != ''].drop_duplicates().sort_values(['VAR1','VAR2']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  VAR1 VAR2 VALUE
0   V1   C1    S1
1   V2   C1    S2
2   V2   C1    S3
3   V2   C1    S4
4   V2   C1    S7
5   V3   C2    S4
6   V3   C2    S5
7   V4   C2    S6
8   V5   C3    S3
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're after the first row corresponding to the groups grouped by making `VAR1` & `VAR2` as the key. In other words, you're dropping all duplicates from these subset but just keeping the first occurence all throughout.

To disregard empty strings from being considered, replace them by `NaN` and stack the `DF` so that these get dropped off completely.

```
grp_f = df.groupby(["VAR1", "VAR2"]).first()
grp_f.replace({"":np.nan}).stack().reset_index([0,1], name="VALUE").reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]