# how to re-arrange multiple columns into one column with same index

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I'm using python pandas and I want to adjust one same index to multiple columns and make it into one column. And when it's possible, I also want to delete the zero value.

I have this data frame

```
index A B C 
a     8 0 1 
b     2 3 0
c     0 4 0 
d     3 2 7
```

I'd like my output to look like this

```
index data value
a     A    8 
b     A    2
d     A    3
b     B    3
c     B    4
d     B    2
a     C    1
d     C    7
```

===
I solved this task as below. My original data has 2 indexes & 0 in dataframe were `NaN` values.

At first, I tried to apply `melt` function while removing `NaN` values following this ([How to melt a dataframe in Pandas with the option for removing NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933696/how-to-melt-a-dataframe-in-pandas-with-the-option-for-removing-na-values)), but I couldn't. 
Because my original data has several columns ('value_vars'). so I re-organized dataframe by 2 steps:

1. Firstly, I made multi-column into one-column by `melt` function,
2. Then removed `NaN` values in each rows by `dropna` function.

[image: Coding Script Snipppet]

Comment: Which version of python are you using? Any particular module of python you import and use for this task? And last but not least, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @araknoid I'm using python 3.6.1. and I was trying to use Pandas for this task. Because I'm new to python, I'm learning modules, packages by applying sample codes. so i was trying to find a code for merging multi-columns into one column while keeping same index. but i could only find methods for "split one-column into multi-columns or merge data in multi-columns into one-column by column rows".. so I uploaded this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a little like the `melt` function in `pandas`, with the only difference being the index.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html

Here is some code you can run to test:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5},'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6}})
pd.melt(df)
```

[image: Image of the my jupter notebook]

With a little manipulation, you could solve for the indexing issue.

This is not particularly pythonic, but if you have a limited number of columns, you could make due with:

```
molten = pd.melt(df)
a = molten.merge(df, left_on='value', right_on = 'A') 
b = molten.merge(df, left_on='value', right_on = 'B') 
c = molten.merge(df, left_on='value', right_on = 'C') 
merge = pd.concat([a,b,c])
```

[image: Merge of the melted data frames]

Comment: thank you! I used melt function and solved this task.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
array = [['a', 8, 0, 1], ['b', 2, 3, 0] ... ]
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']

result = [[[a[i][0], cols[j], a[i][j + 1]] for i in range(len(a))] for j in range(2)]
```

output:

```
[[['a', 'A', 8], ['b', 'A', 2]], [['a', 'B', 0], ['b', 'B', 3]] ... ]
```